# Letsencrypt error DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for etc

Tags: linux, dns, subdomain, ubuntu-18.04, lets-encrypt

i've bought a domain name at google domains:  "yousshark.com"
Then i opened a free account at cloudflare.com to manage my domain name.

I have a cloud VM (droplet) at Digitalocean. An Ubuntu 18.04 base image. I've git cloned a basic node app which serves a simple sentence (just for testing purpose).

Inside cloudflare, i added a record to point to the subdomain "nodejs-ssl-deploy.code" to the server address:

[image]

So after that i entered the following command inside the VM:

```
sudo git clone https://github.com/letsencrypt/letsencrypt /opt/letsencrypt

cd /opt/letsencrypt

./letsencrypt-auto certonly --standalone
```

So the last command offers a prompt to enter the domain for which i want generate a ssl certificate, so i entered "nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com" .
But all i can get is this error :

```
Please enter in your domain name(s) (comma and/or space separated)  (Enter 'c'
to cancel): nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com
Obtaining a new certificate
Performing the following challenges:
http-01 challenge for nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com
Waiting for verification...
Challenge failed for domain nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com
http-01 challenge for nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com
Cleaning up challenges
Some challenges have failed.

IMPORTANT NOTES:
 - The following errors were reported by the server:

   Domain: nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com
   Type:   connection
   Detail: dns :: DNS problem: NXDOMAIN looking up A for
   nodejs-ssl-deploy.code.yousshark.com

   To fix these errors, please make sure that your domain name was
   entered correctly and the DNS A/AAAA record(s) for that domain
   contain(s) the right IP address.
```

I even tried by adding the subdomain inside my google domain page:
[image]

But i all get is this error.
What could be done wrong ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i resolved my issue by adding record manually to the google dns servers, inside the admin of google domains.
If anyone gets the same issue, feel free to contact me.

Comment: Good afternoon, I have the same problem with my local domain. Show in the image: [problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NOElO.png). Can you help?

Comment: how did you fix it

Comment: what records did you add

Comment: there is no way to contact you no email